# Erro: Exception has occurred: TypeError (Python)

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com o seguinte erro na hora de compilar:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'usuario' and 'senha'
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

```py
class Login:

    usuario = str(input("Digite seu usuário: "))
    senha = input("Digite sua senha: ")

    def __init__(self, usuario, senha):
        self.usuario = usuario
        self.senha = senha

    def retorno_usuario(self):
        return self.usuario

    def retorno_senha(self):
        return self.senha


log = Login()

print("O usuário e: {}").format(log.usuario)

print("O usuário e: {}").format(log.senha)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vc não esta compilando, porque python é uma linguagem interpretada, vc esta executando um script. Segundo, vc esta inicializando o objeto `Login` sem argumentos porem especificou na função `__init__` que iniciaria com usuario e senha. Pra corrigir seu erro faça `log = Login('novo-usuario', 'nova-senha')`

O metodo construtor em python se chama `__init__` e é sempre chamado quando tentamos criar um objeto apartir de uma classe, exemplo:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo)
        print(foo)

bar = Foo('python')
```

Comment: Obrigado, cara!

Comment: Sobre "intepretar vs compilar", segue uma leitura interessante: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889798

Comment: Concordo que a vm python `transpila` o código para `bytecode` no instante de execução contudo isso não faz do python uma linguagem compilada uma vez que ele não gera um binário que apos o processo de compilação sera executado pelo processador alvo. Python é uma *linguagem interpretada* que `transpilada` para `bytecode` e tbm pode ser *compilada em C*.